# SQOOP Export failure

Tags: java, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to export a table from HDFS to SQOOP but I am getting java exceptions.
The query I'm using is as follows:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://172.31.54.174/Database --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username user --password userpassword --table accounts --export-dir /user/pri/accounts
```

While execution this query gives me below error:

```
17/03/29 07:54:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/03/29 07:54:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1489328678238_4886_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '\N'
        at accounts.__loadFromFields(accounts.java:691)
        at accounts.parse(accounts.java:584)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
        at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:204)
        at accounts.__loadFromFields(accounts.java:643)
        ... 12 more
```

The file that I am exporting contains data as below :

```
1,2008-10-23 16:05:05.0,\N,Donald,Becton,2275 Washburn Street,Oakland,CA,94660,5100032418,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0

2,2008-11-12 03:00:01.0,\N,Donna,Jones,3885 Elliott Street,San Francisco,CA,94171,4150835799,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0
```

I have also created the table accounts and its structure is as follows:

`+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| acct_num       | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| acct_create_dt | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| acc_close_dt   | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name     | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name      | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| address        | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city           | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state          | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| zipcode        | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone_number   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created        | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modified       | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

I am also attaching a screenshot of the error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your logs '\N' is like escape character so it isnot fitting in varchar.I dont understand why you are adding the same. Also the timestamp format issues is indicated.And also check in your existing data if any column you are using for primary key is repeated itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N'` in your sqoop export command.